# How to hide/show 2 different fragments inside one tab(fragment) of tabbed activity?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I have a tabbed activity and want to show in the first tab:

- listview
- 2 buttons

If one item of listview is clicked i want to show another fragment inside the first tab, with:

- another listview
- another 2 buttons

Then, if the back-button is pressed, i want to return to the previous fragment (in the same tab). If the data of the arraylist of the second listview (while visible) has changed, i want to adopt these changes to the arraylist of the first listview. So i want to access the data of both listviews as easily as possible.

[image]

My first approach is: Everything is in one Fragment with one layout (including different views, which i hide/show). **<- I dont like this, the class getting to huge/confusing.**

My second approach is: First fragment/tab has another viewpager with 2 fragments. **<- i guess this is too complicated (f.i. swiping between main activity tabs interfers with the new viewpager and needs to be handled)**.

**What is the best apprpach for this?**

Answer (score 0):

Create your PageFragment. It will be created by ViewPager adapter and placed inside ViewPager. Use FragmentManager obtained with getChildFragmentManager() method to switch ListFragment's inside PageFragment.

Handling of back pressed event is complicated, you need to provide it from your activity.
Create interface

```
public interface IBackStackManager {

    void addBackStackListener(BackStackListener listener);

    void removeBackStackListener(BackStackListener listener);

    interface BackstackListener {

        boolean onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

Implement it with your activity like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IBackStackManager  {

        private final Deque<BackStackListener> backStackListeners = new ArrayDeque<>();

        @Override
        public void addBackstackListener(BackStackListener listener) {
            backStackListeners.add(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeBackStackListener(BackStackListener listener) {
            backStackListeners.remove(listener);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            boolean result = false;

            if (backStackListeners.size() > 0) {
                BackStackListener listener = backStackListeners.peekLast();
                result = listener.onBackPressed();
            }

            if (!result) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }        
        }

    }
```

In your PageFragment use onAttach and onDetach methods to register back stack listeners

```
class PageFragment extends Fragment implements IBackStackManager.BackStackListener {

   protected IBackStackManager backStackManager;

   onAttach(Context context){
       super.onAttach(context);
       try{
           backStackManager = (IBackStackManager) context;
           backStackManager.addBackStackListener(this);
       } catch(ClassCastException ex){
           ex.printStacktrace();
       }
   }

   onDetach(){
       super.onDetach();
       if (backStackManager != null){
           backStackManager.removeBackStackListener(this);
       }
   }       

   boolean onBackPressed(){
       if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
           getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

}
```